# Huge Array sorting through CORBA and RMI?

Tags: java, sorting, rmi, corba

As a *task* I got to develop an app so a ***client*** sends a 1 million numbers array to a ***CORBA server***. So the server would distribute the sorting task to a few *slaves*.

I honestly don't like CORBA at all, and requirements would accept RMI, so I went for embedding RMI inside the CORBA server. I can get CORBA server seize RMI so far, however, I'm not getting the **array sorted**.

I'll decribe parts of the programm and the relationship among them.

> **CORBA SERVER**

```
import sorting.*;

public class Servidor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // 1. Inicializar ORB
            org.omg.CORBA.ORB orb = org.omg.CORBA.ORB.init(args, null);

            // 2.1 Obtener POA raiz
            POA raizPOA = POAHelper.narrow(orb.resolve_initial_references("RootPOA"));

            // 2.2 Activar el POA manager
            raizPOA.the_POAManager().activate();

            // 3.1 Crear instancia de la implementación (servant)
            propiedadesImplementacion servant = new propiedadesImplementacion();

            // 3.2 Registrar en el POA y obtener referencia al objeto (IOR)
            org.omg.CORBA.Object sortingCORBA = raizPOA.servant_to_reference(servant);

            // 4.1 Obtener el initial naming context
            org.omg.CORBA.Object ncCorba = orb.resolve_initial_references("NameService");
            NamingContextExt nc = NamingContextExtHelper.narrow(ncCorba);

            // 4.2 Asociar un nombre (en el primer nivel)
            nc.rebind(nc.to_name("Proyecto"), sortingCORBA);

            // 5 Quedar a la espera de peticiones

        System.out.println("Proceso servidor en espera ... ");
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rmiregistry");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        ObjetoRemoto or = new ObjetoRemoto();

        Naming.rebind("//localhost/ObjetoRemoto", or);
        System.out.println("Conexión establecida");
            orb.run();  

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error:" + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);

        }
      }
}
```

> **CORBA method Implementation**

```
public class propiedadesImplementacion extends ServidorProyectoPOA {

    public propiedadesImplementacion() {

    }

    public int[] ordenar(int [] a) {


        int[] sub1 = Arrays.copyOfRange(a,0,199999);
        int[] sub2 = Arrays.copyOfRange(a,200000,399999);
        int[] sub3 = Arrays.copyOfRange(a,400000,599999);
        int[] sub4 = Arrays.copyOfRange(a,600000,799999);
        int[] sub5 = Arrays.copyOfRange(a,800000,999999);

       try {

            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("localhost");
            InterfazRMI  i = (InterfazRMI )registry.lookup("objetoRemoto");
            sub1 = i.ordenarRMI(sub1);
            sub2 = i.ordenarRMI(sub2);
            sub3 = i.ordenarRMI(sub3);
            sub4 = i.ordenarRMI(sub4);
            sub5 = i.ordenarRMI(sub5);

            sub2 = merge(sub1, sub2);
            sub3 = merge(sub2, sub3);
            sub4 = merge(sub3, sub4);
            sub5 = merge(sub4, sub5);

            Arrays.sort(sub5);
       }
       catch (Exception e) {}

        return sub5;

    }

    private int[] merge(int[] a, int[] b) {

        int aLen = a.length;
        int bLen = b.length;
        int[] c= new int[aLen+bLen];
        System.arraycopy(a, 0, c, 0, aLen);
        System.arraycopy(b, 0, c, aLen, bLen);
        return c;
    }   
}
```

> **CORBA CLIENT**

```
import sorting.*;

public class Cliente {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try  {

          // 1. Inicializar ORB
          org.omg.CORBA.ORB orb = org.omg.CORBA.ORB.init(args, null);

          // 2.1 Obtener instancia del servidor de nombres (initial naming context)
          org.omg.CORBA.Object ncCorba = orb.resolve_initial_references("NameService");
          NamingContextExt nc = NamingContextExtHelper.narrow(ncCorba);

          // 2.2 Construir el nombre del objeto y obtener ref. desde servidor de nombres
          org.omg.CORBA.Object clienteCorba = nc.resolve(nc.to_name("Proyecto"));

          // 2.4 Convertir el objeto CORBA al tipo Propiedades (narrow) 
          ServidorProyecto  sp = ServidorProyectoHelper.narrow(clienteCorba);

          // 3 Invocar métodos remotos


         int [] a = new int[1000000];
         Random r = new Random();
         for (int i=0; i<1000000; i++) {

             a[i] = r.nextInt(1000000)+1;
//           System.out.print(a[i] + " ");

         }

        a = sp.ordenar(a);

        for (int i=0; i<1000000; i++) {

            System.out.print(a[i] + " ");

         }


        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error:" + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }       
    }
}
```

So, client is simply producing an array (in this case for testing) and calling the `ordenar(int[])` method, that method actually calls some methods registered by RMI which was launched before by server. Array I'm getting back is not exactly sorted. Is the problem in the CORBA-RMI structure or right in sorting implementation?

Comment: Is this for a programming exercise or real world code? Your `merge()` method seems badly broken, how do you assure that all elements from b[] are greater than all from a[]? This doesn't matter as you do an Arrays.sort() afterwards?! And what do you mean with not "exactly sorted" - can you give an example?

Comment: Results I'm getting are really not sorted numbers. I wrote this code as testing.

Comment: 1. Your feelings about CORBA are not relevant. 2. You need to be aware of the existence of RMI/IIOP. 3. This is a very strange task unless it is just an exercise. One million integers doesn't take so long to sort that it is worth all this network overhead, or, frankly, all this effort.

Comment: Yes, it's sort of an exercise

Comment: And you should never have an empty catch block swallowing your exceptions! I suspect you get an exception from RMI call, so your unsorted `sub5` array is returned!